# No resource identifier found for attribute 'filterTouchesWhenObscured' in package android

Tags: android, windows, build, command, android-sdk-tools

I'm using cmd prompt to build a andorid app however I keep getting this BuildFail when I call
ant release or ant debug

https://www.dropbox.com/s/99dit8ctiq3bv4w/error.png

It says:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'filterTouchesWhenObscured' in package android
```

followed by:

```
D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml: null returned: 1
```

Anyone know why this might be happening? I'm thinking maybe I didn't run my android update lib-project command correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

filterTouchesWhenObscured is available since API level 9. The error indicates that you are using some prior API.